# How ISP subnet works with public IP?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, isp

This is maybe a beginner question but I was wondering
how ISP subnet works, if it's like a private local LAN.

If my private IP is: 192.168.1.10 / subnet 255.255.255.0 / gateway 192.168.1.1, then I can talk only with 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254. So how is it that my ISP gives me IP: 66.45.35.65 / subnet 255.255.255.252 / gateway 66.45.35.66 so there is only two IPs in the subnet?

How I can talk with any public IP? The IP 66.45.35.65 going out via the gateway? If yes so how any other public IP can talk directly to 66.45.35.65?

Comment: You will get a quick response to this, but essentially: Routers

Comment: Why do you say that you "can talk only with 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254"?

Comment: @user1686 inside the local lan i mean , without getting out via the WAN

Comment: Okay, but later you're specifically asking about WAN addresses: "how i can talk with any public ip?" – How are those two situations related? Why do other public IP addresses need to talk _directly_ to 66.45.35.65 instead of indirectly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is routers, or more specifically IP routing...

Your computer can talk directly any device within your subnet (your LAN), which is based on the IP address and subnet mask. The subnet mask tells your computer the size or range of your local subnet (your LAN).

You have a router, either that you supplied or your ISP supplies that sits in your LAN as your gateway (192.168.1.1) and has an interface on the public Internet (66.45.35.65)... If your computer needs to talk to an IP address outside of your local LAN subnet, it sends it to the gateway (your router) which then knows it either needs to send the traffic directly to a local IP on the public side (of which there is no other usable address) or out to the gateway of the public Internet side (66.45.35.66). This processes continues throughout the internet of your packet getting to a router, then the router deciding if it services that IP directly, knows a specific router to take to get there, or it just hands it off to it's gateway (another router) and that process continues until the destination is reached.

So basically, your network address and subnet tell your computer what is local, if it isn't local then the traffic is sent to the router (gateway address) to be handled and routed out of your network. So in your case if the destination is 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255, your computer talks directly to that device... if the destination is outside of that it passes the information to the router (gateway address of 192.168.1.1) to handle the routing to the next network hop for routing to it's destination.

So technically the answer is routers.

This is a very simple explanation, and lots of factors can effect this, but this is a quick and simple overview.

Comment: thanks for the overview
my public ip is: 66.45.35.65 on subnet 255.255.255.252 , and my gateway 66.45.35.66
so im going out with 66.45.35.66 so when public ip trying to talk to me how he can talk
to 66.45.35.65 , if im going out via 66.45.35.66 . he need to talk to 66.45.35.66 i think

Comment: No... 66.45.35.65 is your usable IP... all communication in or out is with that IP, the gateway (66.45.35.66) is just that, a gateway or routing point, neither you nor the far end communicate directly with it. To see what IP the "public" sees, go to https://ipchicken.com